# Google Maps in Sencha Touch

Tags: google-maps, extjs, touch

I wanted to have an Map in my Sencha Touch Application. I loaded the script in index.html and I can see that it is active, because the Browser is looking for my actual location.

The problem is that everything from the view loads, but I can see no map.

My view looks like this:

```
Ext.define('RMA-App.view.ActivityMap', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.activitymap',

    initialize: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        var backButton = {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'back',
            text: 'Zurück',
            handler: this.onBackButtonTap,
            scope: this
        };

        var topToolbar = {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Ort der Aktivität',
            items: [
                backButton,
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer'
                }
            ]
        };

        var map = {
            xtype: 'map',
            useCurrentLocation: true
        };

        this.add([
            topToolbar,
            map
        ]);
    },

    onBackButtonTap: function() {
        console.log('backToActivityEditorCommand');
        this.fireEvent('backToActivityEditorCommand', this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving a layout to your parent container.  In my experience, the default layout on the view doesn't properly render a map as a child.

```
Ext.define('RMA-App.view.ActivityMap', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.activitymap',
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        }
    },  

    ...
```

As an aside, note that the Ext.map inherits from Ext.container, so if all you're doing is adding a toolbar, you could add it to the map container itself and remove a level of nesting.

Comment: With layout fit, I get this error message: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onItemAdd'. And even the topToolbar isn't shown.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I neglected to realize that the layout is applied differently within a view.  I edited the post above to reflect. If you use this config, it works.  Check out http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/JQHc8/ for an example.